# Understanding かな with the te-form

Tags: grammar, particles, て-form, song-lyrics

I'm trying to understand the following clause from the World of Final Fantasy opening song, [Innocent²](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Innocent%C2%B2).

> 君の大事なものを教えて
> 僕らの目にも映るかな

I know that the かな particle often means 'I wonder' and has other uses. The phrase's first half reads something like, "Tell an important thing about you," and the second half reads like, "We wonder if it will reflect in our eyes too." It's throwing me off because the phrases don't sound right when put together and interpreted forwards and backward.

Also, given how the lyrics are arranged, they're probably separate clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, these two lines are two independent sentences. A te-form as a request is used at the end of the sentence.
- 君の大事なもの is not "important thing about you" but "the (most) important thing to you" or "the thing you value".
- 目に映る is a set phrase that simply means "to be visible to one's eyes". See [this dictionary definition](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AB%E6%98%A0%E3%82%8B).

So those two lines can be translated like so:

> 君の大事なものを教えて。
> Tell me what you value most.
>
> 僕らの目にも映るかな。
> I wonder if we can see it too.

Answer (score 0):

I think much of it is open for interpretation. The two lines, and other lines in the song for that matter, seem only loosely connected. There are some thematic consistency between lines, but that's about it.

If you ask what is supposed to be reflected (映る), I cannot put my finger on it. It could be 君の大事なもの in the previous line, but it could be something else. The only justification for it I find is "because they are close to each other in the lyrics" which is not much.